# Why I can't animate the SCNnode on eulerAngle using CAKeyframeAnimation

Tags: swift, animation, scenekit, arkit

I'm try to animate an SCNnode using CAKeyframeAnimation, I been able to change the position of my object without problem but I can't animate the change of EulerAngle property.

The following code change the position of the node.

```
func animatePlaneKey(nodeToAnimate: SCNNode){

    let pos = nodeToAnimate.position
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    let pos1 = SCNVector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z)
    let pos2 = SCNVector3(pos.x + 1 , pos.y, pos.z)
    let pos3 = SCNVector3(pos.x + 1 , pos.y, pos.z + 1)

    animation.values = [pos1,pos2, pos3]
    animation.keyTimes = [0,0.5,1]
    animation.calculationMode = .linear
    animation.duration = 10
    animation.repeatCount = 1
    animation.isAdditive = true   
        
    nodeToAnimate.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "position")
}
```

and the following one should change the eulerAngles property but does't work.
any idea why I can't animate the rotation?

```
func animatePlaneKey(nodeToAnimate: SCNNode){

    let animation2 = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "rotation")
    let angles = nodeToAnimate.eulerAngles
    let rot0 = SCNVector3(angles.x, angles.y, angles.z)
    let rot1 = SCNVector3(angles.x, angles.y + Float(deg2rad(45)) , angles.z)
    animation2.values = [rot0, rot1]
    animation2.keyTimes = [0, 1]
    animation2.duration = 2
    animation2.repeatCount = .infinity
    animation2.isAdditive = true

    nodeToAnimate.addAnimation(animation2, forKey: "rotation")
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I recommend: SCNAction.rotate(by: around, duration) - i.Ex: let rotate = SCNAction.rotate(by: CGFloat.pi*2, around: SCNVector3(0,1,0), duration: 5.0) - this will rotate the node on the Y axis by 360 degrees. You can repeat SCNAction - also forever.

Comment: SCNNode rotation property is an SCNVector4. Change the rotation to SCNVector4, or change the keyPath to "eulerAngles".

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ***SCNVector4*** type (a.k.a. Quaternion) instead of ***SCNVector3*** type (a.k.a. Euler).

And a key *"spin around"* instead of *"rotation"*.

```
let ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)!

let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "rotation")
let start = SCNVector4(0, 0, 0, 0)
let end = SCNVector4(0, 1, 0, CGFloat(Float.pi * 6))

animation.fromValue = start
animation.toValue = end
animation.duration = 10
animation.repeatCount = .infinity

ship.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "spin around")
```

Comment: I'll try soon as possible your solution, thanks a lot...,